# ubuntu 20.04 Booting from flash drive fails at checking disks

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

So i am trying to boot from a flash drive but every time i try to do so when i reach the checking disks the the laptop turns off (got past this point only once and and it also never booted) also when creating the bootable drive it took like 35 mins if that is of any help

Laptop Dell xps 9560

Comment: I am not sure if i did anything wrong i followed the steps in the following link https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview                I am a total noob to this so i am following the basics

Answer (score 0):

### Removing Disk Check on Persistent USB's

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` will still come up but **fsck** will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

**mkusb** After the Persistent USB drive is created, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Persistent menuentry thus:

`linux  ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip quiet splash persistent ---`

- **Newer versions of mkusb already include this fix**

**UNetbootin** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the first menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open syslinux.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the default menuentry for (BIOS boot mode).

**Rufus** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Default menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open /isolinux/txt.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the "Try Ubuntu without installing" menuentry, (for BIOS boot mode).

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from BIOS boot by overwriting syslinux.cfg with:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting an Ubuntu Persistent session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt --
```