# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04 hangs indefinitely (24 hours)

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

I've got an old HP Phoenix desktop computer.  I've installed Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 20.04 on this system (the 20.04 being an in-place upgrade from 18.04).

I had some inconsistencies with some application software in the 20.04 version of the system.  I tried the same software on a clean installation of 20.04 on another system (Dell XPS), and everything was OK.

Hence, I decided to do a clean reinstall of 20.04 on the HP system.  I set up four partitions: efi, swap, /, /home, in that order, and I opted not to format /home.

I tried installing from a USB flash drive, and that appeared to work, but the installer just hung (for hours).  I tried this multiple times.  Same result.

I tried the same thing with a DVD drive.  Again, multiple tries.  Again, same result.

I've let the current installation run for 24 hours.  The slide show still works fine, and the progress thingy is still spinning, but I'm guessing it's never going to finish.

Some other information: (1) the disk drives all pass the test at the start of the installation.  (2) I've tried the installation on two different disk drives.  (3) The "Try Ubuntu" option works fine, as did the Ubuntu 14.04 system (before I wiped it out with the failed attempt at installation).  Hence, there's reason to believe that the hardware is OK.

I'm happy to acknowledge that there might be cockpit error here, but I'm at a loss to figure this out.  If it's obvious what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

But I'd also like to know if there's some way to diagnose the situation.  It's frustrating just to sit there and stare at the spinning circle.  I've tried CTRL-ALT F_n but was unable to get any information from the alternate screens.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Michael: Does this happen when "Checking Disks"? If so The disk check can easily be eliminated: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249010/ubuntu-20-04-booting-from-flash-drive-fails-at-checking-disks/1249075#1249075

Comment: I've done this with and without disk checks.  Disks always check OK.  Problem is much further downstream, after I've answered all the questions (partitions, time zone, login name, etc.) and hit "Install now" (or similar).  The slide show starts, eventually ends, but the circle keeps spinning forever.  How to diagnose?